# why the control is going to "End Sub" directly?

Tags: vba, excel

I have used a variable named rng as Range.
I have found the last row by using:

```
lastrow = tmpSheet.Cells(tmpSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

& after finding a word in a Foundcell(Range format) using:

```
Set Foundcell = tmpSheet.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(What:="ABC")

Do Until Foundcell Is Nothing
      Set rng = tmpSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 1))
       .
       .
        (Copy the row from a aheet to another)
       .
       .
errHandler:


End Sub
```

After getting the value in Foundcell the control goes to End Sub directly from the line **"Set rng"** . I am not getting Why it's happening ?

Comment: Why would you not supply the entire code? How can we see what the problem is?

Comment: Think you have the code 'On Error Goto errHandler', Remove or comment that line and try to run the code again error message will appears and you can see what error occurs on that line.

Comment: It's not throughing any error, just left the line 
set rng to End Sub .
I have put some breakpoint too.
no problem in the code , have checked .The problem is in Set rng line only.

Comment: @ShubhenduOjha as Adisak says, most likely that is the case as it will not throw an error and will go to the line marked :errHandler instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting the range Cells(1,1) to Cells(lastrow,1) on tmpsheet, you should change the Set Rng line to:

```
Set rng = Range(tmpSheet.Cells(1,1), tmpSheet.Cells(lastrow,1))
```

instead.

Comment: Yes!! it worked but can you please tell me why 
Set rng = tmpSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 1))
 is not working in some scenario but works for some?
means difference b/w both

Comment: the code you gave will only work when tmpSheet is the ActiveSheet  because Cell(1,1).value refers to Range("a1") of the activesheet and not tmpSheet. Hence using tmpSheet.range(Cells(1,1), Cell(lastrow,1)) returns error because they are not found in tmpSheet but rather in the ActiveSheet.

Comment: @Stanly: Can you  please give an answer on my question
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098813/i-want-to-apply-a-loop-on-working-code-so-it-will-able-to-work-on-single-click]
I am stuck in this ... please answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You did not supply the entire code, but this is probably what you are looking for.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim tmpSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PasteSH As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set tmpSheet = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set PasteSH = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With tmpSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    End With

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c = "ABC" Then
            c.EntireRow.Copy PasteSH.Cells(PasteSH.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```